# Count rows based on text in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I was tasked to make a Userform in Excel to, at a click of a button,

- Sort through thousands of cells of data (close to 10k at one go).
  Count data by type, categorized as: To be incorporate, Won't be incorporated, incorporated, partially incorporated, replaced by other ea.
- My goal is to create a table in which it is able to input from the press of the button, the counts of these rows.
- The code must also be able to skip the hidden rows whilst also being able to count them.

This code counts however much there is for all five types. It is unable to count the remaining such as, the total amount of rows including both hidden and unhidden, total amount of hidden rows, total amount of rows where it does not contain any of the five data types.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

Columns("P:x").ColumnWidth = 27.5
Columns("P:x").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Columns("p:x").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Dim R As Long
Dim L As Long
Dim N As Long
Dim P As Long
Dim O As Long
Dim A As Long
Dim F As Long
Dim G As Long
Dim col As Range, i As Integer

Dim c As Long
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim M, range_1 As Range
Set range_1 = Range("J1").EntireColumn
With range_1
    R = Worksheets("Default").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For L = 2 To R
        If Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, "J") = "Incorporated" And (Worksheets("Default").Rows(L).EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
            N = N + 1
        End If
        If Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, "J") = "To be incorporated" And (Worksheets("Default").Rows(L).EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
            M = M + 1
        End If
        If Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, "J") = "Won't be incorporated" And (Worksheets("Default").Rows(L).EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
            O = O + 1
        End If
        If Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, "J") = "Partially incorporated" And (Worksheets("Default").Rows(L).EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
            P = P + 1
        End If
        If Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, "J") = "Replaced by other EA" And (Worksheets("Default").Rows(L).EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
            G = G + 1
        End If
    Next
End With
Worksheets("default").Cells(R, "P") = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
A = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R, "s") = N
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R, "R") = M
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R, "U") = O
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R, "q") = N + M + O + P + G
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R, "T") = P
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R, "V") = G
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R, "w") = (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count - (N + M + O + P + G)) - 1
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R - 1, "s") = "EAs that are incorporated"
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R - 1, "R") = "EAs that are To be Incorporated"
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R - 1, "U") = "EAs that won't be Incorporated"
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R - 1, "q") = "EAs with an incorporation status"
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R - 1, "T") = "EAs with partially incorporated"
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R - 1, "w") = "EAs without incorporation status"
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R - 1, "P") = "Visible EAs"
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R - 1, "x") = "Non-visible EAs"
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R - 1, "V") = "EAs Replaced by other EA"
Worksheets("Default").Cells(R, "x") = R - A - 1
MsgBox A

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is very ineficcient.

```
For L = 2 To R
    If Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, "J") = "Incorporated" And (Worksheets("Default").Rows(L).EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
    N = N + 1
    End If
    If Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, "J") = "To be incorporated" And (Worksheets("Default").Rows(L).EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
    M = M + 1
    End If
    If Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, "J") = "Won't be incorporated" And (Worksheets("Default").Rows(L).EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
    O = O + 1
    End If
    If Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, "J") = "Partially incorporated" And (Worksheets("Default").Rows(L).EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
    P = P + 1
    End If
     If Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, "J") = "Replaced by other EA" And (Worksheets("Default").Rows(L).EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
    G = G + 1
    End If    
Next
```

Imagine `Cells(L, "J")` is `Incorporated` why would you still go further and check if it is all the others if you already know they cannot be. Your code just wastes time then.

```
For L = 2 To R
    If Worksheets("Default").Rows(L).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        Select Case Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, "J")
            Case "Incorporated":            N = N + 1
            Case "To be incorporated":      M = M + 1
            Case "Won't be incorporated":   O = O + 1
            Case "Partially incorporated":  P = P + 1
            Case "Replaced by other EA":    G = G + 1
        End Select
    End If
Next L
```

So this would first check if the row is not hidden. And only then check the value of column `J`. Once `Select Case` finds a value it stops checking for the others.

---

To your counting issue:

Do not use `ActiveSheet` instead specify the sheet you mean by name. Do never let Excel guess which sheet to look at, the active sheet might change by a single mouse click during code execution.

The issue with your counting is that the following

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
```

will give you only the amount of rows of the first area of a non-continous range.
If you need to know the number of all visible rows you need either loop through all areas and sum up.

Or as a workaround you can do:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Resize(ColumnSize:=1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
```

The trick here is to limit the used range to one column using `Resize(ColumnSize:=1)` and count the visible cells there (which is the same number as visible rows) but with the difference that this is counting the total number over all areas!

Comment: Hello, yes it definitely speeds up the code. Thank you for this. However, My A value seems to be broken. I need it to count all the cells in the row that is fully visible and not hidden, as one of the cells needs to have a count of the non-visible ones, which i put the formula as (sum of visible cells - sum of non-visible cells). Do you have any solution? the code works perfectly fine if i have no cells hidden at all, but the moment any cell is hidden the code just decides to commit seppuku and give wrong values.

Comment: holy, works like a charm. Thanks so much! For some reason, i had this command without the used range nor the resize and the macro would either give me 1 or the max number of columns 100% of the time. Thanks a lot, genuine lifesaver